# Introduction to astronomy

Tags: discussion, resources

I'm really interested in astronomy since I began watching the night sky with my binoculars and found the view above me so beautiful. For some reason, I didn't notice that we had such a thing above us, being part of our daily life and considering it as something that has to be without questioning myself, too immersed with human things (school, etc.). Anyway, I wanted to know what would be a good way to begin learning about astronomy ? What would be some good books that I could learn from ? (I don't have the educational background as professional astronomers do, for now.)

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

You could find your local astronomy club and see if they have "Star Parties" where members bring their telescopes to some dark field once a month or so and show off the universe to anyone who shows up. Everything you see will be something real and meaningful to you in a different way.

Be warned, though, that you might get hooked, and end up owning a couple of thousand dollars worth of really cool equipment.